# How do I get a reference value from fieldRef in Kubernetes?

Tags: kubernetes

When I do a `kubectl get pod pod_name -o yaml` I have a field like this.

```
    - name: MY_NODE_NAME
      valueFrom:
        fieldRef:
          apiVersion: v1
          fieldPath: spec.nodeName
```

I wanted to know the value of this `MY_NODE_NAME`.

Unfortunately, I cannot do a `env` or `exec` to my pod. Is there any way to get the value of this reference?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I cannot do a env or exec to my pod. Is there any way to get the value of this reference?

Try:
`kubectl get pod <name> --namespace <ns> -o jsonpath='{.spec.nodeName}'`